# Cant submit form

Tags: javascript, php

Basically I've got a form with 5 radio buttons. No submit button. I want the form to run when the user clicks on any of the radio buttons, so this is what I did.

```
<input id="5" type="radio" name="star" onchange="this.form.submit();" <?php if ($row["star"] =="5") echo "checked";?> value="5"/>
```

a querystring is required for the form so I'm using a form action like this

```
<form name="submit" action="http://example.com/page.php?id=<?php echo $urlid;?>&title=<?php echo $title;?>" method="POST">
```

and my php is

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $rating = $_POST['star'];
    $title = $_GET['title'];
    $verification = ($_GET['verification']);
} else {
    //run the page like usual
}
```

After testing, I found that onclick, it runs the form action, but on the php side, it goes to "else" where is runs the page like usual instead. Any ideas?

Comment: the `name` element of `<form>` is not submitted/posted. you could add a hidden element with name submit - `<input type="hidden" name="submit">` OR just use your radio name `if(isset($_POST['star']))`

Comment: Sending something in the URl like `?id=thisthat` doesn't make it a `POST`

Comment: It seems the form element has an action attribute with no closing quote and no space before the method attribute, probably causing the form to be submitted as `GET` instead

Comment: also your `action` is missing a closing quote, and no space before `method`.

Comment: the form action looks wrong

Comment: `$POST['submit']` assumes you have an input in your form with the name `submit`. Which as you said, you don't have, so your logic moves straight to the else statement.

Comment: my mistake. was typing too fast. Anyway, I've used Sean's answer with the isset. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP is checking if `$_POST['submit']` contains a value. Your form does not contain a form element with the attribute `name="submit"`, so therefore it fails and moves straight to the **else** statement.

If you want to check if the form was posted then you should instead check for:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {}
```

or

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The form element seems to have invalid attributes, missing a quote and space.
It's generally easier to write a little more code, and keep it clearer

```
<?php
   $url = "http://example.com/page.php?id=". $urlid ."&title=". $title;
?>

<form name="submit" action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking with -

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) { // this checks whether there is any item named 'submit' inside the POST or not
} else {
    //run the page like usual
}
```

The easiest would be to put a hidden item with name `submit` so that the check validates to true-

```
<form .. >
     ....
     <input type='hidden' name='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```